# Retrieving data from the session

Tags: php, octobercms

How to retrieve data in .htm page using twig.

```
    public function onRun()
    {
        $captchaImagePath = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/install-master/storage/app/uploads/captcha/';
        Log::info($captchaImagePath);

        $captchaImageUrl = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/install-master/storage/app/uploads/captcha/';

        $captchaFontPath = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/install-master/storage/app/uploads/fonts/verdana.ttf';

        $val = array(
                'word_length' => 5,
                'word' => '',
                'img_path' => $captchaImagePath,
                'img_url' => $captchaImageUrl,
                'font_path' => $captchaFontPath,
                'img_width' => '150',
                'img_height' => 30,
                'expiration' => 7200
               );

        $img_path=$captchaImagePath;
        $img_url=$captchaImageUrl;
        $font_path=$captchaFontPath;

        $captcha = $this->create_captcha($val,$img_path,$img_url,$font_path);
        $url = Request::url();
        if (ends_with($url, ['.html', '.htm']))
        {
            $url = str_replace(['.html', '.htm'], '', $url);
            return Redirect::to($url, 301)->with($captcha);
        }
        Log::info($url);
        Log::info($captcha);

        }

the function in same file  public function create_captcha($data = '', $img_path = '', $img_url = '', $font_path = '')
    {

//        Log::info($data);
//        Log::info($img_path);
//        Log::info($img_url);
//        Log::info($font_path);

        if(!isset($data['word_length']))
        {
            $length=5;
        }
        else
        {
            $length=$data['word_length'];
        }

        //Log::info($length);


        $defaults = array('word' => '', 'word_length' => $length,'img_path' => '', 'img_url' => '', 'img_width' => '150', 'img_height' => '30', 'font_path' => '', 'expiration' => 7200);
      //  Log::info($defaults);

        foreach ($defaults as $key => $val)
        {
            if ( ! is_array($data))
            {
                if ( ! isset($$key) OR $$key == '')
                {
                    $$key = $val;
                   // Log::info( $$key);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                $$key = ( ! isset($data[$key])) ? $val : $data[$key];
            }
        }
      //  Log::info($img_path);        Log::info($img_url);

        if ($img_path == '' OR $img_url == '')
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ( ! is_dir($img_path))
        {
            return FALSE;


            }


        if ( ! is_writable($img_path))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ( ! extension_loaded('gd'))
        {
            return FALSE;

        }

        // -----------------------------------
        // Remove old images
        // -----------------------------------

        list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
        $now = ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);

        $current_dir = @opendir($img_path);

        while($filename = @readdir($current_dir))
        {
            if ($filename != "." and $filename != ".." and $filename != "index.html")
            {
                $name = str_replace(".jpg", "", $filename);

                if (($name + $expiration) < $now)
                {
                    @unlink($img_path.$filename);
                }
            }
        }

        @closedir($current_dir);

        // -----------------------------------
        // Do we have a "word" yet?
        // -----------------------------------

        if ($word == '')
        {
            //$pool = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $pool = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $str = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $word_length; $i++)
            {
                $str .= substr($pool, mt_rand(0, strlen($pool) -1), 1);
            }

            $word = $str;
        }

        // -----------------------------------
        // Determine angle and position
        // -----------------------------------

        $length = strlen($word);
        $angle  = ($length >= 6) ? rand(-($length-6), ($length-6)) : 0;
        $x_axis = rand(6, (360/$length)-16);
        $y_axis = ($angle >= 0 ) ? rand($img_height, $img_width) : rand(6, $img_height);

        // -----------------------------------
        // Create image
        // -----------------------------------

        // PHP.net recommends imagecreatetruecolor(), but it isn't always available
        if (function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor'))
        {
            $im = imagecreatetruecolor($img_width, $img_height);
        }
        else
        {
            $im = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height);
        }

        // -----------------------------------
        //  Assign colors
        // -----------------------------------


        $bg_color       = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $border_color   = imagecolorallocate ($im, 232, 244, 252);
        $text_color     = imagecolorallocate ($im, 57, 136, 190);
        $grid_color     = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 239, 253);
        $shadow_color   = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 240, 240);
        // -----------------------------------
        //  Create the rectangle
        // -----------------------------------

        ImageFilledRectangle($im, 0, 0, $img_width, $img_height, $bg_color);

        // -----------------------------------
        //  Create the spiral pattern
        // -----------------------------------

        $theta      = 1;
        $thetac     = 7;
        $radius     = 16;
        $circles    = 20;
        $points     = 32;

        for ($i = 0; $i < ($circles * $points) - 1; $i++)
        {
            $theta = $theta + $thetac;
            $rad = $radius * ($i / $points );
            $x = ($rad * cos($theta)) + $x_axis;
            $y = ($rad * sin($theta)) + $y_axis;
            $theta = $theta + $thetac;
            $rad1 = $radius * (($i + 1) / $points);
            $x1 = ($rad1 * cos($theta)) + $x_axis;
            $y1 = ($rad1 * sin($theta )) + $y_axis;
            imageline($im, $x, $y, $x1, $y1, $grid_color);
            $theta = $theta - $thetac;
        }

        // -----------------------------------
        //  Write the text
        // -----------------------------------

        $use_font = ($font_path != '' AND file_exists($font_path) AND function_exists('imagettftext')) ? TRUE : FALSE;


        if ($use_font == FALSE)
        {

            $font_size = 5;
            $x = rand(0, $img_width/($length/3));
            $y = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $font_size  = 16;
            $x = rand(0, $img_width/($length/1.5));
            $y = $font_size+2;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++)
        {
            if ($use_font == FALSE)
            {
                $y = rand(0 , $img_height/2);
                imagestring($im, $font_size, $x, $y, substr($word, $i, 1), $text_color);
                $x += ($font_size*2);
            }
            else
            {
                $y = rand($img_height/2, $img_height-3);
                imagettftext($im, $font_size, $angle, $x, $y, $text_color, $font_path, substr($word, $i, 1));
                $x += $font_size;
            }
        }


        // -----------------------------------
        //  Create the border
        // -----------------------------------

        imagerectangle($im, 0, 0, $img_width-1, $img_height-1, $border_color);

        // -----------------------------------
        //  Generate the image
        // -----------------------------------

        $img_name = $now.'.jpg';

        ImageJPEG($im, $img_path.$img_name);

        $img = "<img src=\"$img_url$img_name\" width=\"$img_width\" height=\"$img_height\" style=\"border:0;\" alt=\" \" />";

        ImageDestroy($im);

        return array('word' => $word, 'time' => $now, 'image' => $img);
    }

}
```

now how to use captcha which is image + word created through above function in
 **default.htm**

```
<span id="captcha">

    <img src="{{captcha.image}}" width="150" height="30" style="border:0;" alt=" " />   </span>
```

the file created by above function saves in given path bt how to show that image when form appears...................................................................................................................................................

Comment: What is your question? Why do you want to read from a session using a variable?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to correct your syntex, to flash session while redirecting you need to use

```
with('name', 'value')
```

so you need to use

```
if (ends_with($url, ['.html', '.htm']))
{
    $url = str_replace(['.html', '.htm'], '', $url);
    return Redirect::to($url, 301)->with('captcha', $captcha); // <- correct this
    // $this->create_captcha() must return string value
    // here $captch seems object/image so you should not pass objects in session
}
```

instead I guess you need to pass some random value

```
$someRandomValue = 'blabla';

$val = array(
    'word_length' => 5,
    'word' => '', // <----------------- something here [$someRandomValue]
    'img_path' => $captchaImagePath,
    'img_url' => $captchaImageUrl,
    'font_path' => $captchaFontPath,
    'img_width' => '150',
    'img_height' => 30,
    'expiration' => 7200
);
```

and then pass it like

```
with('captcha', $someRandomValue)
```

and now in other place you can get it by

```
$captchaValue = session::get('captcha')
```

so this `$captchaValue` will be same as `$someRandomValue`

> in short in last you need `user input as text/string` and compare with `$captchaValue` (this will be from session) to validate it

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: please look back to my que